# Splash screen api Android white box on landscape mode

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm doing some tests in my app to take them to the others, but I have a problem implementing the splash screen api. Rather, the problem I have is with the result on the screen once I take the device to landscape mode. A white "box" appears at the start or end of the device. This happens in emulator as in physical devices.

*Edit I have used the same api in another app without ads and I get the same result.

[device with start white box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JW39n.png)

[device with end white box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFcsu.png)

**MainActivity**

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    installSplashScreen()
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    initializeComponent()


    buttonBanner.setOnClickListener {
        AdsManager(this).showBanner(bannerLayout, this)

    }
    buttonInter.setOnClickListener {
        AdsManager(this).showInterstitial(this)
    }
    buttonReward.setOnClickListener {
        AdsManager(this).showReward(this)
    }
}
```

**Xml Splash**

```
<style name="Theme.App.Starting" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">

    <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/teal_700</item>

    <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground</item>

    <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.UnityAds</item>
</style>
```

**Manifest**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name=".UnityAds"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.App.Starting" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.App.Starting"
       >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**Xml main_activity**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/teal_700"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonBanner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
    android:text="Show Banner"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buttonInter"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonInter"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
    android:text="Show Interstitial"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buttonReward"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/buttonBanner" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonReward"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
    android:text="Show Reward"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/buttonInter" />

<include
    android:id="@+id/bannerLayout"
    layout="@layout/banner_layout"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/buttonReward" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Banner layout**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:layout_width="320dp"
android:layout_height="50dp">
```

**Theme**

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.UnityAds" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

Comment: Add more info   your unity theme and banner layout

Comment: I have implemented the same api in another app without ads and I get the same result. When th device is on landscape mode the "box" appear

Comment: Include all tags in your layout main_activity (parent layout not found).